# Получение html кода с сайта с помощью WebClient C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, есть [ссылка](https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1234) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе по ней есть такой html код, внутри которого содержится информация, которую нужно спарсить.

есть `WebClient`

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
```

нужно узнать html код, используя webclient, возможно ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По ссылке, которую вы дали - выдает `XML` формат([FOAF](https://habrahabr.ru/post/18263/)) , как `HTML` документ вы видите его в браузере для удобства чтения.

В вашем примере для получения строки, достаточно написать

```
var data = client.DownloadString("https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1234");
```